# Ng5 npm getting 'Cannot find module './topologicalSort''

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an **Angular 5** app. When I try to run it I'm getting the below error on an `npm start`.

```
Error: Cannot find module './topologicalSort'
```

I think this is something to do with 'webpack' but I have no idea how to solve the issue.

The full error is here...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/app/socialFeed/socialFeed.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module './topologicalSort'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\TileCase\V4\TileCase.V4.UI\node_modules\postcss-modules-extract-imports\lib\index.js:15:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\TileCase\V4\TileCase.V4.UI\node_modules\css-loader\lib\processCss.js:14:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
 @ ./src/app/socialFeed/socialFeed.component.scss 2:21-151
```

My webpack common file looks like this...

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const helpers = require('./helpers');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 *
 * problem with copy-webpack-plugin
 */
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');


/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  const isProd = options.env === 'production';
  const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, options.metadata || {});
  const ngcWebpackConfig = buildUtils.ngcWebpackSetup(isProd, METADATA);
  const supportES2015 = buildUtils.supportES2015(METADATA.tsConfigPath);

  const entry = {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    main:      './src/main.browser.ts'
  };

  Object.assign(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin, {
    tsConfigPath: METADATA.tsConfigPath,
    mainPath: entry.main
  });

  return {
    /**
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: entry,

    /**
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {
      mainFields: [ ...(supportES2015 ? ['es2015'] : []), 'browser', 'module', 'main' ],

      /**
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      /**
       * An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
       */
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

      /**
       * Add support for lettable operators.
       *
       * For existing codebase a refactor is required.
       * All rxjs operator imports (e.g. `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` or `import { map } from `rxjs/operator/map'`
       * must change to `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'` (note that all operators are now under that import.
       * Additionally some operators have changed to to JS keyword constraints (do => tap, catch => catchError)
       *
       * Remember to use the `pipe()` method to chain operators, this functinoally makes lettable operators similar to
       * the old operators usage paradigm.
       *
       * For more details see:
       * https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking
       *
       * If you are not planning on refactoring your codebase (or not planning on using imports from `rxjs/operators`
       * comment out this line.
       *
       * BE AWARE that not using lettable operators will probably result in significant payload added to your bundle.
       */
      alias: buildUtils.rxjsAlias(supportES2015)
    },

    /**
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      rules: [
        ...ngcWebpackConfig.loaders,

        /**
         * To string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * To string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
         * Returns compiled css content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /**
         * File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
         */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },

        /* File loader for supporting fonts, for example, in CSS files.
        */
        {
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        }

      ],

    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      /**
       * Plugin: DefinePlugin
       * Description: Define free variables.
       * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
       *
       * Environment helpers
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
       */
      // NOTE: when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'AOT': METADATA.AOT,
        'process.env.ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'process.env.HMR': METADATA.HMR
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'polyfills',
        chunks: ['polyfills']
      }),

      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        minChunks: Infinity,
        name: 'inline'
      }),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'main',
        async: 'common',
        children: true,
        minChunks: 2
      }),


      /**
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
        { from: 'src/meta'}
      ],
        isProd ? { ignore: [ 'mock-data/**/*' ] } : undefined
      ),

      /*
      * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
      * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
      * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
      * which changes every compilation.
      *
      * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
          const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
          return entryPoints.indexOf(a.names[0]) - entryPoints.indexOf(b.names[0]);
        },
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'body',
        xhtml: true,
        minify: isProd ? {
          caseSensitive: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          keepClosingSlash: true
        } : false
      }),

       /**
       * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
       * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
       *
       * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        sync: /inline|polyfills|vendor/,
        defaultAttribute: 'async',
        preload: [/polyfills|vendor|main/],
        prefetch: [/chunk/]
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin),

      /**
       * Plugin: InlineManifestWebpackPlugin
       * Inline Webpack's manifest.js in index.html
       *
       * https://github.com/szrenwei/inline-manifest-webpack-plugin
       */
      new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin(),

    ],

    /**
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

My package.json looks like this...

```
    {
  "name": "tilecase",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "tilecase",
  "keywords": [
    "tilecase"
  ],
  "author": "TileCase",
  "homepage": "https://www.tilecase.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:aot:dev": "cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run build:dev",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "docs:compodoc": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
    "docs:compodoc:serve": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s",
    "docs:compodoc:serve:watch": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s -w",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "node": "node",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hotOnly",
    "server:aot:dev": "cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:aot": "npm run server:aot:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:aot:dev": "npm run build:aot:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:aot:prod": "npm run build:aot:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "5.0.0",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.2.9",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.28",
    "angular2-moment": "0.8.2",
    "angular4-social-login": "1.1.1",
    "angulartics2": "1.6.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "googlemaps": "1.12.0",
    "http-server": "0.10.0",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "6.1.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.2.6",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "0.9.0",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "3.2.3",
    "ng2-social-share": "0.0.10",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "0.1.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.0.32",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.9.5",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "7.0.39",
    "@types/source-map": "0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.16",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "find-root": "1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.9.1",
    "karma": "1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "ngc-webpack": "4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "4.6.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "1.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.0.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.8.5",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "0.7.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-svgstore-plugin": "3.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you upload you webpack file?

Comment: sure, what would you be looking for in it?

Comment: wanna be sure where you error is coming from

Comment: I have added my common webpack file

Comment: Can you try this and check `node-sass rebuild -f`

Comment: cmd doesn't know that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you delete the **node_modules** dir completely, then you should delete this two dependencies from your `package.json`

```
"css-loader": "0.28.11",
"sass-loader": "7.0.0",
```

After which you run `npm install`, then you run these again:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that. I think its something to do with the updated package versions that are now being pulled.

Comment: is it okay if you update your question with the `package.json`

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Happy to know it work. I suspect there's a problem with `"sass-loader"` version ` "7.0.0"`.